# Advice on making website form mobile friendly

Tags: html, mobile-website

I want to make my website more mobile friendly.  For example, I'd like to declutter the input forms when viewed on a mobile device.  My search form holds 5 fields for different search criteria, but I'd like the form to change to *1* field with a drop down box when viewed on a mobile device.

And would this make make my website more responsive, or would this be a pointless change?

I'm thinking the HTML would go from this:

```
<!-- ... -->
  <td align="right">Client Ref :</td>
  <td align="left"><input type="text" name="sp:def:address_id" size="9" maxlength="9"></td>
  <td align="right">Invoice Number :</td>
  <td align="left"><input type="text" name="sp:def:invoice_number" size="9" maxlength="9"></td>
  <td align="right">Email :</td>
  <td align="left"><input type="text" name="sp:def:email" maxlength="100"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="right">Last Name :</td>
  <td align="left"><input type="text" name="sp:def:last_name" maxlength="36"></td>
  <td align="right">Postcode :</td>
  <td align="left"><input type="text" name="sp:def:postcode" size="10" maxlength="9"></td>
  <td align="left"> </td>
<!-- ... -->
```

...to something like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="#">Client Ref</option>
  <option value="#">Invoice Number</option>
  <option value="#">Email</option>
  <option value="#">Last Name</option>
  <option value="#">Post Code</option>
</select>
<input name="" type="text" size="40"/>
```

Comment: Why even have 5 boxes at all, from a UX points of view it only needs one.  The backend should be able to search for the correct entity, without needing hints from the UI to find whatever it is you're looking for based on your requirements.

Comment: i am new to php and all the fields run of different backend file and do not know how to create a single script that can search three database tables at the same time as invoices and post code are in they own tables